# Can't communicate on open port between terminal sessions on Amazon instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, firewall

I realise that the firewall should not block traffic moving between terminal sessions on the same server, but I have included detail of my firewall here as it might be related somehow. The crux of this problem is "What linux/AWS setting could be stopping me from communicating on a port on the same instance"

I have an amazon instance (not build by me) running Debian. I am trying to get an email relay running, but that question is in another post. For starters, I just want to make sure that a port is open. The way I do this on other servers is, I make sure the firewall is not blocking the port, and then get netcat to listen on that port. So, for my instance I went to AWS security management and opened port 2525 both UDP and TCP
[image]
nothing is blocked outbound

[image]

and checked the local firewall

```
root@lamp # iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sun Feb 28 10:36:57 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [727933:41936189]
:INPUT ACCEPT [727933:41936189]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4341889:262878645]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4341889:262878645]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 28 10:36:57 2016
```

Then I ran netcat to listen on port 2525

```
root@lamp # nc -l 2525
```

logged on via a different terminal session to the same server

```
root@lamp /home/www# nc localhost 2525
localhost [127.0.0.1] 2525 (?) : Connection refused
root@lamp /home/www# netstat -anp | grep 2525
root@lamp /home/www# telnet localhost 2525
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I try this on my ubuntu laptop or on my rackspace instance, the nc command should get me a kind of chat session which I terminate with a CTRL^D.

I am not too familiar with the way Amazon do things, so I guess I am missing some AWS web interface, but what confuses me is I would expect all traffic to be free to travel between different sessions on the same localhost. Any light that could be shed on allowing traffic on this port would be appreciated.

Comment: Outbound should be used to expose the port to the outer world from the server, inboud for opening access to the server

Comment: Thanks. I figure  though that whatever the external firewall is set to, I should still be able to connect to an open port from the same machine. Confusing....

Answer (score 1):

AWS Security Groups wouldn't be getting involved here in terms of opening + connecting to the server locally.

It's only relevant when trying to connect to and from other servers.

I suspect your issue is a Linux configuration issue, but of what flavour I do not know.